# Google drive api to get all children is not working if I dynamically pass fileId to query

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying google drive api to search parents of a folder. In search query i have to pass file id dynamically instead of hard coding. I tried below code. but I am getting file not found json response.

here its not taking fileId as value i think its consider as String
if I hardcode the value it is working.
FileList result =  service.files().list().setQ("name='testfile' ").execute();

```
    for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : result.getFiles()) {
        System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
            file.getName(), file.getId());

       String fileId =file.getId();

        FileList childern =  service.files().list().setQ(" + \"file.getId()\" in parents").setFields("files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType)").execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
String fileid=file.getId()

 service.files().list().setQ("'" + fileId + "'" + " in parents").setFields("files(id, name, modifiedTime, mimeType)").execute();
```

Make sure you have valid `file.getId()`

Answer (score 0):

I know your question states java but the only [sample](https://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/) of this working is in C#.  Another issue is as far as i know [PageStreamer.cs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/2df445ea9fce00868cf0a1ea010cb40ef6ed64a8/Src/Support/Google.Apis/Requests/PageStreamer.cs) does not have an equivalent in the java client library.

I am hoping that C# and java are close enough that this might give you  some ideas of how to get it working in Java. My java knowledge is quote basic but i may be able to help you debug it if you want to try to convert this.

```
try
            {
                // Initial validation.
                if (service == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("service");

                // Building the initial request.
                var request = service.Files.List();

                // Applying optional parameters to the request.
                request = (FilesResource.ListRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);

                var pageStreamer = new Google.Apis.Requests.PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File, FilesResource.ListRequest, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList, string>(
                                                   (req, token) => request.PageToken = token,
                                                   response => response.NextPageToken,
                                                   response => response.Files);

                var allFiles = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList();
                allFiles.Files = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>();

                foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(request))
                {
                    allFiles.Files.Add(result);
                }

                return allFiles;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Request Files.List failed.", Ex);
            }
```

Comment: My problem is with query  " + \"file.getId()\" in parents"   is there any way dynamically pass fileid instead of hardcoding

Comment: file.getId() isnt hard coded its the file id from the current file you are looping though right now

Comment: I am iterating over children of a folder and getting file Id. Its not hard coded

Comment: If I hardcode it works, i tried It, but how do I pass dynamic ID to that query